# How can I get the data entered by the user in C using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

```
    //get choice input 
    int n;
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    // print the option that the user entered i.e. you chose option 2
    printf("you chose option %n /n" ,n);
```

Sorry for the newbie question; I haven't done C coding before!

Comment: Seems unduly harsh to downvote this question.  Upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem i see with that code is the descriptor from `printf`. It should be `%d`. Also is `\n` not `/n` for the new line ( but that doesn't cause any problems). So try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
       //get choice input 
        int n;
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        // print the option that the user entered i.e. you chose option 2
        printf("you chose option %d \n" ,n); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work either, it saying that `n` isn't identified¬¬

Comment: well i edited my post now, if you just copy it it works fine.

Comment: The return value from `main()` is of type `int` - see the C standard (§5.1.2.2.1: '_The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
parameters:
`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner._'

Comment: `c(74): error C2065: 'n' : undeclared identifier` this is the error im getting

Comment: @Suliaman: You must be doing something very funny to be getting that error.  You haven't shown us all the code you're using.  Have you got mismatched comments, perhaps?  It appears that the compiler is not seeing your declaration of `int n;`.  Is it at the far right of the line containing the `// get choice input` comment, so that it appears to be wrapped but is actually on the same line?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.  First `%n` is (horrifyingly) an output item; it writes to a pointer to `int` - and you don't provide it with a pointer to `int`, so you invoke undefined behaviour.  Use `%i` or `%d` (most usually `%d`) for a plain (signed) integer.

You also won't see the `printf()` output until you output a newline, or the program terminates, because you mistyped the newline escape sequence (it is `\n`, not `/n`).  Thus, your code

```
printf("you chose option %n /n" ,n);
```

should be revised to:

```
printf("you chose option %d\n", n);
```

Finally (for now), you should also validate the return value from `scanf()`; if it tells you it failed to convert anything, you should not try using `n`:

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
    printf("you chose option %d\n", n);
else
    printf("Oops - failed to read an integer from your input\n");
```

Note that if the user typed 'a' (say), then no amount of retrying to read the integer will work.  You probably need to gobble up the rest of the line of input:

```
else
{
    printf("Oops - failed to read an integer from your input\n";
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}
```

Now it is safe to go back and try again.